# How can I access properties of an interface controller which has been presented modally in an array?

Tags: objective-c, watchkit

I'm presenting an array of `InterfaceControllers` from a menu controller using this code:

```
[self presentControllerWithNames:@[@"ControllerA",
                                   @"ControllerB",
                                   @"ControllerC"]
                        contexts:nil];
```

Is there any way I can access "ControllerB" to set some properties or pass it some data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can. with the same method only.
Instead of passing nil value you can pass whatever information you want.

```
[self presentControllerWithNames:@[@"ControllerA",@"ControllerB"] contexts:@[dict1,dict2]];
```

> Each object in the array is passed to the interface controller at the
>   same index in the names parameter.

Reference: [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceController/presentControllerWithNames:contexts:)

Comment: Wow I was staring at this the whole time too... thanks! So if there are no contexts for Controller A I would just pass an empty dictionary or could I pass [NSNull null]?